# deleting certain rows with multiple tables T-SQL

Tags: database, t-sql

I have a database with multiple tables.  I want to remove entries that has a column ID with a certain value.  Is there a way to do this in T-SQL given that there might be tables that might not even have a column ID?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use dynamic sql to create command that delete records from all tables with column 'id' in database:

```
declare @idToDelete varchar(max) = '10'

declare @sql nvarchar(max) = ''

set @sql =
(
select 'delete ' + object_name(c.object_id) + ' where id = ' + @idToDelete +  char(10)
from sys.columns c 
    join sys.objects o on o.object_id = c.object_id
    join sys.schemas s on s.schema_id = o.schema_id
        and s.name = 'dbo'
where c.name = 'id'     
for xml path('')
)

print @sql

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: Thanks! the way we have it at work, they literally had 100 lines of delete this from ... and i just wanted to know if there's a dynamic way to do it in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

There will be a way to join the tables. Start by building a select ie

```
select table1.something,
       table2.somethingelse,
       table3.somethingelse2
From   Table1,
       Table2,
       Table3
Where  Table1.ColumnID in ('ID1','ID2','ID3')
And    Table1.SomeColumn = Table2.SomeColumn
And    Table2.AnotherColumn = Table3.AnotherColumn
```

When you get all your data returning and you have verified that it is indeed what you need to delete, you can change the select to a delete from.

If you are not confident with this though I would maybe generate the select and hand it off to a DBA to change and execute.

Comment: Beware the [Wrath of Aaron](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)!  Just sayin'.

Comment: Thanks :). Funny thing is the first comment on that post: "I see a lot of people with Oracle experience". Yeah that pretty much sums me up, been using Oracle for the last 13 years, I have done a little MS Sql many years ago (then more recently played around with crosstabs in MS SQL) and now live in an Informix environment but I know my SQL skills need to be brushed up on, for the purpose of this example they would get by :).